# how to change Na with other columns?

Tags: r, dataframe

I Have 2 indicator:

```
       licence     age.6-17
         Na         1
         1          0
         Na         0
         0          1
```

how I can change Na to 1 if a person is more than 17 years (that is second column is 0) old and 0 otherwise?

output

```
       licence     age.6-17
         0          1
         1          0
         1          0
         0          1
```

Comment: You can just do `ifelse(df$age.6.17 == 1, 0, 1)`

Comment: Just to clarify because of the answers given so far: Is `Na` "not a value" `<NA>` or is it a string value `"Na"`?

Comment: it is actually NA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `dplyr` and `ifelse`

```
yourdata %>% mutate(licence = ifelse(`age.6-17` == 0, 1,0))
```

No need to change how the nature of `"Na"` nor the column name.

In addition, in case you would need to replace only the `"Na"` cells, considering `"Na"` is a string here

```
yourdata %>% mutate(licence = ifelse(licence == "Na" & `age.6-17` == 0, 1,0))
```

If however it is `<NA>` you would need `is.na(licence)` instead of `licence == "Na"`

Answer (score 1):

In *base* you can subset with `is.na` and then subtract the value of `age.6.17` from 1.

```
x  <- read.table(header=T, na.string="Na", text="licence     age.6-17
         Na         1
         1          0
         Na         0
         0          1")

idx <- is.na(x$licence)
x$licence[idx]  <- 1-x$age.6.17[idx]
x
#  licence age.6.17
#1       0        1
#2       1        0
#3       1        0
#4       0        1
```

or in case you ignore what is actualy stored in column `licence` you can use:

```
with(x, data.frame(licence=1-age.6.17, age.6.17))
#  licence age.6.17
#1       0        1
#2       1        0
#3       1        0
#4       0        1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `NA`s are actual `NA` we can use `case_when` in `dplyr` and apply the conditions.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(licence = case_when(is.na(licence) & age.6.17 == 0 ~ 1L, 
                             is.na(licence) & age.6.17 == 1 ~ 0L, 
                             TRUE ~ licence))

#  licence age.6.17
#1       0        1
#2       1        0
#3       1        0
#4       0        1
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(licence = c(NA, 1L, NA, 0L), age.6.17 = c(1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: it didn't change my licence column

Comment: @shere Did you assign the result back ? Also I assume those are actual `NA`s.